# C-Array output is different than expected for same printf()

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I'm attempting to do a "find the bug" assignment, and this small bit of C code (not runnable as is) is supposed to have a bug in it.  Unforunately I can't find one.  I put it into runnable code and it seems to run as expected...is this a trick question or am I missing something?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Code snippit:

```
void example(int a[10]){
        int i = 0;
        do {
           a[i] = i++;
        }while (i < 10);
    }
```

My runnable code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

example(int a[10]){
    int i = 0;
    do {
       a[i] = i++;
       printf("%i", a[i-1]);  //decremented by 1 to offset i
    }while (i < 10);
}

int main(void)
{
   int arr[10];    
   example(arr);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0123456789
```

Comment: arr[10] is not initialized

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong and invokes undefined behavior:

```
a[i] = i++;
```

There is no sequence point specified for the assignment, increment or index operators, you don't know when the effect of the increment on i occurs.

Take a look to [Question 3.1 of C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/expr/evalorder1.html)